# How to turn a list into a circular list in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list [0,1,0] and would like to iterate through it, and look at each item's neighbors (neighbor = 2 indexes away) and update the value (1 changes to 0 and vice versa) if the neighbor has the same value. When iterating through and reaching the last item in the list, I want to start over at the 0th index of the list. So the neighbor for the item in the 1st index is actually the item in the 0th index in the above example with a list of length 3.

I also want to be able to determine the number of times that I iterate over the list.

I am able to update the value of an item in the list if its neighbor (2 indexes away) has the same value, but I run into trouble with an Index out of range error when I get to the last items in the list. To get around this, I tried popping the last item from the list and appending it to the beginning so I don't fall off the end of the array, but I don't get the expected result (see result below), and I'm uncertain why.

I have also tried using `cycle` from `itertools` which is great for iterating through, but not for accessing elements at a specific list get the value of the list at a certain index.

The results from popping and appending are as follows:

```
[0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
```

I want the results to be as follows:

```
original list = [0,1,0]
after 1 time step | [1,1,0]
after 2 time steps | [1,0,0]
after 3 time steps | [1,0,1]
```

and so on.

Comment: Does your list repeat itself, and what is that repeatable pattern @JohnWachter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was not clear but what I interpreted from your question is that you may be looking for traversing a list in circular fashion and updating it's values.
Try this out

```
   list = [0,1,0]
   key=2;
   for i in range(len(list)):
      index = (i+key)%len(list);
      if list[i] == list[index]:
          list[i] = int(not list[i]);
      print(list);
```

Comment: Your approach works great, and from what I can tell the modulo is used to keep the index 2 in front of whatever the value of i is at the current time, brilliant. One thing I think your response is missing is a parameter to decide how many times I would go over the list, which would be easy to add:                                                             
thelist = [0,1,0]
key=2;
p = 0
while p <5:
    for i in range(len(thelist)):
      index = (i+key)%len(thelist);
      if thelist[i] == thelist[index]:
          thelist[i] = int(not thelist[i]);
      print(thelist)
    p+=1

Comment: Thank you, Happy to help !! But are you sure you understood concept of how modulo and key was playing around? If any doubts, please let me know, will clear it.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific task, I'd keep initial list in the same order and check indexes:

```
l = [0, 1, 0]

n = 0
while n < 1:  # choose number of iterations
    for i in range(len(l)):
        l[i] = (l[i], int(not l[i]))[l[i] == l[(i+2)%len(l)]]  # invert when equal to its neighbor 
        print(l)
    n += 1

# [1, 1, 0]
# [1, 0, 0]
# [1, 0, 1]
```

---

While, in order to make a list *circular*, I'd rather append the first index to the last instead:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
for _ in range(7):
    print(l)
    f = l.pop(0)
    l.append(f)

#[1, 2, 3]
#[2, 3, 1]
#[3, 1, 2]
#[1, 2, 3]
#[2, 3, 1]
#[3, 1, 2]
#[1, 2, 3]
```

---

You can get same results also by popping and appending, but you'll have to sort indexes according to the original list at every step:

```
for i, _ in enumerate(range(3)):
    l[0] = int(not(l[0])) if l[0] == l[2] else l[0]
    ind = (len(l) - i)%len(l)  # get actual position of first element
    original = l[ind:] + l[:ind]  # here we start from index 0
    print(l[ind:] + l[:ind])
    f = l.pop(0)
    l.append(f)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks, your first example is exactly what I was looking for. I had also tried the pop and append, but ran into issues, so apparently I did not want a true circular list, thanks for helping clarify that. I'm unclear on how using the modulo function gets around the index out of range error, can you please help elaborate on that?

Comment: Glad it helped. I updated my answer showing how you can get same results with pop and append, if you are interested